# Roblox Error with 'attempt to index nil with `GetRankInGroup`'

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a ChalkBoard that runs a presentation. When you click a button on the SurfaceGUI, it should be playing a presentation. The presentation function works. However, when it checks its player ranks, it will say the error (in the title). I know that `game.Players.LocalPlayer` can only be used in LocalScripts. But I instead used `(function(player)` because I thought that was the only way it would work. This could be a bit hard to understand, so I'll take some pictures of the errors and script.

```
local groupid = 6554102


local rankid = 205


local wait_time = 5


local faces_text = {
    first = "Left, Face - Turn left 90 degree";
    second = "Right, Face - Turn right 90 degrees";
    third = "About, Face - Turn 180 degrees";
    fourth = "Left, Incline - Turn left 45 degrees";
    fifth = "Right, Incline - Turn right 45 degrees";
    sixth = "Control, eyes - Follow the host using your eyes";
    seventh = "Center, Face - Face the host";
}


local rules_text = {
    first = "1. Soldiers never abuse guns, guns are only for combat, using guns for other reasons or abusing will result in being arrested.";
    second = "2. Soldiers never let civilian's trespass, only allied personnel are allowed into base.";
    third = "3. Only go into your divisions area, never into other division's areas.";
    fourth = "4. Never go into places your not suppose to go into unless authorized to.";
    fifth = "5. Tanks, trucks, and halftracks are for combat or for driving long distances only.";
}


local ranks_text = {
    first = "[PVT] Private";
    second = "[LCPL] Lance Corporal";
    third = "[CPL] Corporal";
    fourth = "[SGT] Sergeant";
    fifth = "[SSGT] Staff Sergeant";
    sixth = "[SGT-MAJ] Sergeant Major (Obtainable by Gamepass)";
    seventh = "[OCAD] Officer Academy Cadet ";
    eight = "Allied Personnel (BSM Diplomats)";
    ninth = "[LT] Lieutenant";
    tenth = "[CPT] Captain";
    eleventh = "[MAJ] Major";
    twelth = "[LTCOL] Lieutenant Colonel";
    thirteenth = "[COL] Colonel";
    fourteenth = "[GS] General Staff";
    fifteenth = "[FM] Field Marshal";
    sixteenth = "[PM] Prime Minister";
    seventeenth = "[GG] Governor General";
    eighteenth = "[HM] His Majesty";
}


local board = script.Parent
local ChalkGUI = board.ChalkGui
local StartFrame = ChalkGUI.StartFrame
local FacesFrame = ChalkGUI.FacesFrame
local RulesFrame = ChalkGUI.RulesFrame
local RanksFrame = ChalkGUI.RankFrame
local buttons = StartFrame.buttons

buttons.faces.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(player)
    if player:GetRankInGroup(groupid) >= rankid then
    
    StartFrame.Visible = false
    
    FacesFrame.Visible = true
    
    FacesFrame.text.Text = faces_text.first
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    FacesFrame.text.Text = faces_text.second
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    FacesFrame.text.Text = faces_text.third
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    FacesFrame.text.Text = faces_text.fourth
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    FacesFrame.text.Text = faces_text.fifth
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    FacesFrame.text.Text = faces_text.sixth
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    FacesFrame.text.Text = faces_text.seventh
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    FacesFrame.Visible = false
    
    StartFrame.Visible = true
    else
        
    end
end)

buttons.ranks.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(player)
    if player:GetRankInGroup(groupid) >= rankid then
    
    StartFrame.Visible = false
    
    RanksFrame.Visible = true
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.first
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.second
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.third
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.fourth
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.fifth
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.sixth
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.seventh
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.eight
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.ninth
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.tenth
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.eleventh
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.twelth
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.thirteenth
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.fourteenth
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.fifteenth
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.sixteenth
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.seventeenth
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.text.Text = ranks_text.eighteenth
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RanksFrame.Visible = false
    
    StartFrame.Visible = true
    else
        
    end
end)

buttons.rules.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(player)
    if player:GetRankInGroup(groupid) >= rankid then
    
    StartFrame.Visible = false
    
    RulesFrame.Visible = true
    
    RulesFrame.text.Text = rules_text.first
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RulesFrame.text.Text = rules_text.second
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RulesFrame.text.Text = rules_text.third
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RulesFrame.text.Text = rules_text.fourth
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RulesFrame.text.Text = rules_text.fifth
    
    wait(wait_time)
    
    RulesFrame.Visible = false
    
    StartFrame.Visible = true
    else
        
    end
end)
```

Comment: Heyo, you've got all the right pieces for a great question but could you edit your question and copy-paste your code into your question? Images of code are not useful for us to help you debug it. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Okay, I changed it. Hope that helps now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message you're trying to index a nil value with `GetRankInGroup`.

In two lines you do this:

`player:GetRankInGroup(groupId)` where `player`is a nil value.

When the `MouseButton1Clicked` event is fired the function you connected will be called.

```
buttons.faces.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(player)
    if player:GetRankInGroup(groupid) >= rankid then
-- ...
```

Where exactly should that `player` come from? It is not provided when your event handler is called. Please refer to the Roblox manual.

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/GuiButton

Under Events you'll find

> `RBXScriptSignal MouseButton1Click ( )` Fired when the mouse has fully
> left clicked the GUI button

note that the parenthesis are empty.

Compare this to for example:

> `RBXScriptSignal MouseButton1Down ( int x , int y )` Fired when the
> mouse is in the left mouse down state on the GUI object

Here you could connect a `function (x,y)`.